# Running 2 installations of Wordpress in Docker

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, portainer

I'm trying to run 2 separate installations of Wordpress in Docker, but I'm having conflicts with the databases.

Here's what I've tried so far:

I runned the below code and got the logs also below.

Open putty > nano docker-compose.yml > pasted the below code > docker-compose up -d

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress_multi_1:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 11:80 ##change_this
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_multi_1
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser_multi_1
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass_multi_1
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb_multi_1
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_1:/var/www/html ##change_this

  db_multi_1:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb_multi_1
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser_multi_1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass_multi_1
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'   #I didn´t changed this
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_3/db1:/var/lib/mysql

  # Other Instalation
  wordpress_multi_2: #2nd_instance
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 12:80 ##change_this
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_multi_2 #point to 2nd db instance
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser_multi_2
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass_multi_2
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb_multi_2
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_2:/var/www/html ##change_this

  db_multi_2: #2nd_instance
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb_multi_2
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser_multi_2
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass_multi_2
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'  #I didn´t changed this
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_2/db2:/var/lib/mysql

volumes: ##remove these line if you bind the volume to host machine
  wordpress_multi_1:
  db_multi_1:
  wordpress_multi_2:
  db_multi_2:
```

I can´t access the first container in MY-IP:11 ,
when I access 2nd container MY-IP:12 I get this error message Error establishing a database connection

I have this in the container logs:

In the Logs of root wordpress multi _1_1  I have this

```
[25-Jul-2020 15:53:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
WARNING: unable to establish a database connection to 'db_multi_1'
  continuing anyways (which might have unexpected results)
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.27.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.27.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Jul 25 15:53:30.918212 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.4.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 25 15:53:30.918429 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

In the Logs of root_db_multi_1_1  I have this

```
2020-07-25 15:53:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user exampleuser,
2020-07-25 15:53:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user exampleuser access to schema exampledb,
,
2020-07-25 15:53:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server,
2020-07-25T15:53:59.954860Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully,
2020-07-25T15:53:59.954994Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads,
2020-07-25T15:53:59.955028Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients,
2020-07-25T15:53:59.955057Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events,
2020-07-25T15:53:59.955668Z 0 [Note] Binlog end,
2020-07-25T15:53:59.957922Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.957982Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958006Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958027Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958045Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958138Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958162Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958196Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958218Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958240Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958257Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958274Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958291Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958308Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958325Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958378Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958400Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958421Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958439Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958458Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958477Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958496Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958515Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958535Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958555Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958575Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958595Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958614Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958633Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958652Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958672Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958696Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958715Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958732Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958755Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958773Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958792Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.958813Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB',
2020-07-25T15:53:59.959041Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.,
2020-07-25T15:53:59.959779Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...,
2020-07-25T15:54:00.060456Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool,
2020-07-25T15:54:00.062402Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200725 15:54:00,
2020-07-25T15:54:02.601970Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12578970,
2020-07-25T15:54:02.606084Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1",
2020-07-25T15:54:02.606173Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY',
2020-07-25T15:54:02.606192Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV',
2020-07-25T15:54:02.606207Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password',
2020-07-25T15:54:02.606218Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password',
2020-07-25T15:54:02.606496Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog',
2020-07-25T15:54:02.610743Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete,
,
2020-07-25 15:54:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped,
,
2020-07-25 15:54:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.,
,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.386358Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.392303Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.31) starting as process 1 ...,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.404842Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.404912Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.404931Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.404949Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.404967Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.404984Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.405903Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.406261Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.412184Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.450230Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.458769Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.477366Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.572954Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables,
2020-07-25T15:54:03.573169Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.136273Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.140875Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.140953Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.142674Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.194101Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.31 started; log sequence number 12578970,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.196142Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.198000Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.214845Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200725 15:54:04,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.223928Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.223996Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.225843Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.225943Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.227467Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.227657Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.227691Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.227764Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.259808Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.296032Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events,
2020-07-25T15:54:04.298053Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.,
Version: '5.7.31'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL),
```

In the Logs of root wordpress multi_2_1 I have this:

```
[25-Jul-2020 15:53:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22,
,
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused,
[25-Jul-2020 15:53:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES) in Standard input code on line 22,
,
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
,
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
,
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
,
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
,
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
,
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
,
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
,
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
,
MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
,
WARNING: unable to establish a database connection to 'db_multi_2',
  continuing anyways (which might have unexpected results),
,
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.27.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message,
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.27.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message,
[Sat Jul 25 15:53:30.922486 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.4.8 configured -- resuming normal operations,
[Sat Jul 25 15:53:30.922705 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND',
192.168.1.21 - - [25/Jul/2020:15:53:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 2952 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36",
192.168.1.21 - - [25/Jul/2020:15:53:49 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 2952 "http://192.168.1.198:12/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36",
192.168.1.21 - - [25/Jul/2020:16:01:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 2952 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36",
192.168.1.21 - - [25/Jul/2020:16:01:08 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 2952 "http://192.168.1.198:12/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36",
```

In the Logs of root_db_multi_2_1  I have this

```
2020-07-25 15:53:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.,
2020-07-25 15:53:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql',
2020-07-25 15:53:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.349210Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.355966Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.31) starting as process 1 ...,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.369477Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.369554Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.369574Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.369600Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.369618Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.369636Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.370895Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.371337Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.379153Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.423703Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.432259Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.449044Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.749813Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 12578846,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.750534Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 12578855,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.750614Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.750659Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.952127Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1",
2020-07-25T15:53:03.952210Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables,
2020-07-25T15:53:03.952808Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.161161Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.168757Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.168874Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.172052Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.31 started; log sequence number 12578855,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.173264Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.174026Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.187982Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200725 15:53:05,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.195363Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.195433Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.197818Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.197923Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.199723Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.199889Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.199923Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.199996Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.232986Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.269606Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events,
2020-07-25T15:53:05.271134Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.,
Version: '5.7.31'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL),
2020-07-25T15:53:06.493594Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T15:53:09.499889Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T15:53:12.505293Z 4 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T15:53:15.510159Z 5 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T15:53:18.515748Z 6 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T15:53:21.522246Z 7 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T15:53:24.528657Z 8 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T15:53:27.534936Z 9 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T15:53:30.538996Z 10 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T15:53:49.230001Z 11 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T15:53:49.697588Z 12 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T16:01:07.993591Z 13 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
2020-07-25T16:01:08.232897Z 14 [Note] Access denied for user 'exampleuser'@'172.27.0.5' (using password: YES),
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or fix the code/stack I tried to run? I'm not an experienced user.

I had other installations of Wordpress in the past that I deleted and I am thinking that may be causing the conflicts... I don't know... I tried some diferences in the stack files that I searched the internet, renamed the containers, but I keep getting the same errors, and I am out of ideas.

Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks.

I'm running Open Media Vault > Docker > Portainer.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Important information about your question should not only be available through external links as links can break or change over time. Please edit your question to include all the information necessary to explain the problem as clearly and succinctly  as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the editing and i´ll try in the future avoid external links. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got sorted! You should consider accepting the answer from @TSB99X if it helped, so that the question gets marked as resolved and other users know that it is useful if they also have similar problems. Plus you both get some rep points :)

Comment: you´re right, already done it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding multiple volumes under same root of `wordpress_multi_2`.This is not a good way to mount volumes. Split them to separate folders (example for `/wp` and `/db`). And do not bind ports under 1024, as they are reserved, common convention for plaintext HTTP ports is like 8080 on development machines.

```
wordpress_multi_1:
    ...
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    ...
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_1/wp:/var/www/html

db_multi_1:
    ...
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_1/db:/var/lib/mysql

wordpress_multi_2: #2nd_instance
    ...
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    ...
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_2/wp:/var/www/html

db_multi_2: #2nd_instance
    ...
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_2/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work!! And i even run a second Stack with a 3 and 4 installation just to check!

Following your advice, i changed the paths and the ports, and also added some things to the code, to be honest i´m not sure on what worked, but it´s working!

i added this:

```
links:
  - db_multi_1
depends_on:
  - db_multi_1
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

One thing i noticed is that mysql container takes some minutes to fully start, only after that, the wordpress / MY-IP:8001 can work correctly.

Thanks for pointing me in the wright direction.

Full Stack:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  wordpress_multi_1:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8001:80 ##change_this to above 1024
    links:
      - db_multi_1
    depends_on:
      - db_multi_1      
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_multi_1
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser_multi_1
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass_multi_1
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb_multi_1
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_1/wp:/var/www/html ##change_this #Split them to separate folders (example for /wp and /db)

  db_multi_1:
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password  
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb_multi_1
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser_multi_1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass_multi_1
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1' #don´t change
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_1/db:/var/lib/mysql

#    networks:
#      local


# Other INstalation

  wordpress_multi_2: #2nd_instance
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8002:80 ##change_this
    links:
      - db_multi_2
    depends_on:
      - db_multi_2      
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_multi_2 #:3306 #point to 2nd db instance
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser_multi_2
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass_multi_2
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb_multi_2
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_2/wp:/var/www/html ##change_this

  db_multi_2: #2nd_instance
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password #resulta?
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb_multi_2
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser_multi_2
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass_multi_2
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1' #don´t change
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-1TB/Config/wordpress_multi_2/db:/var/lib/mysql
#    networks:
#      local      

volumes: ##remove these line if you bind the volume to host machine
  wordpress_multi_1:
  db_multi_1:
  wordpress_multi_2:
  db_multi_2:
```